# Change license from Ritchey Extra Permissive License v2 to Zero-Clause BSD

Tags: license-compatibility, relicensing, 0bsd

Can I take something which is licensed under the [Ritchey Extra Permissive License v2](https://jamesdanielmarrsritchey.blogspot.com/2020/01/ritchey-extra-permissive-license-v2.html), and use the sub-licensing clause to distribute it under the [Zero-Clause BSD](https://opensource.org/licenses/0BSD) license?

Comment: Hopefully no one is using that crayon license.

Answer (score 3):

I have already written [on the subject of relicensing](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/4194/2870); if you read the whole of that question you can see my answer reflects a viewpoint which is widely-, but far from universally-, held.

From that viewpoint I don't see a problem with what you want to do.  In the first place, the Ritchey EPL v2 does not require you to convey either the code itself, or derivative works thereof, under that licence; this to my mind is all the permission you need.  But he goes further, as you point out, and explicitly permits "*sub-licensing*" (whatever he means by that) "*under terms which do not require further permissions from the owner than granted by this license*", which 0BSD does not.  If I were you, I'd just do it.

It seems to me that this Ritchey fellow [has form](https://jamesdanielmarrsritchey.blogspot.com/search/label/licenses) when it comes to licence proliferation, and anything you can do to propagate a body of otherwise-usable code without the attached handicap of one of his superfluous crayon licences is a good thing.